# Difference between sqoop and TDCH

Tags: teradata, sqoop, bigdata

Need detailed difference between Sqoop and TDCH- Teradata Connector for Hadoop. Which is recommended for Teradata as source and hadoop as a Target?.
We need to implement different type of loads like Incremental , History and Append

Comment: The Teradata connector supports JDBC FastLoad/FastExport, which should at least potentially out-perform the generic Sqoop connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata doesnt have concept of Primary Key's instead they use Primary Index(PI) or Unique Primary Index (UPI) and they are used for the data distribution purpose in TD AMPs

So when you use sqoop with number of mappers or split by column that point of time we wont be making use of the TD capability of **fastexport** utility.

In sqoop even though if you mention 50 mappers with **-m** parameter, when the data is exported to HDFS all the data would be residing in a single part file.

So in order make use of TD and HDFS distribution we must use TDCH jar while exporting data from TD into HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

TDCH supports hive, HCatalog, but does not support all file formats: only supports TextFile, SequenceFile, and RCFile.

Now, almost all hadoop distributions have added sqoop Teradata connector, so you can use all sqoop features (Incremental , History, Append etc.) which TDCH does not support:

[cloudera-connector-for-teradata](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/01/cloudera-connector-for-teradata-1-0-0/)

[hwx-connector-for-teradata](https://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hwx-connector-for-teradata.pdf)

[four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive](http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/)

[MapR-teradata-connector-hadoop-yarn](https://www.mapr.com/blog/teradata-connector-hadoop-yarn-mapr)

[IBM - biginsights](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.import.doc/doc/data_warehouse_teradata-import.html)

Edit: removed this line from original answer as per Dev's input:

> For Teradata as source you have to use TDCH, sqoop doesn't not have direct support for Teradata.

Comment: Apache Sqoop directly supports Teradata. All you need to add JDBC jar like for other RDBMS.

Comment: but don't we need connection manager like - this - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76555/problem-while-connecting-to-teradata-with-sqoop? and I was referring to this doc-https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_databases in reference to direct support for teradata.

Comment: This works fine with sqoop 1.4.6 - `sqoop export -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=1 --connect 'jdbc:teradata://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=ds_tbl_db' --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --username xxx --password  xxx --table hive_01 --export-dir <dir> --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' -m 2`

Comment: Thanks for your input @dev  ツ, I removed the misleading line from answer, and my mind  ツ. . .

Comment: I understand that  Sqoop comes up with different loading options (Incremental , History, Append etc.) So which one is recommended TDCH or SQOOP for Teradata as source ?.. I have started my work by writing Python Script to decide the Load Type and loading using TDCH. So switching to Sqoop is still better option ?. Please Help

Comment: Yes - that way you will only have to maintain one tool, you can reuse sqoop scripts, you can store in all sqoop supported file types while with TDCH you are limited to 3 file types and also you will get some additional features than TDCH when you need to some delta data transfers.